# how to take the standard deviation and sum of a count(*) result column

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table as such:

```
firstname  lastname   values
john       doe        first
john       doe        second
john       doe        third
joe        public     first
joe        public     second
robert     willians   first
robert     willians   second
```

I would like to count the number of times each firstname, lastname pair occurs. then calculate the sum, average, and standard deviation of the count column.

Currently, I have:

```
select stddev(t.count(*)), avg(t.count(*)), sum(t.count(*))
   from (select count(*), firstname, lastname
      from table
      group by firstname, lastname) t
```

This gives

> unknown user-defined functions t."count(*)",t."count(*)",t."count(*)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a more meaningful column alias:

```
select stddev(t.cnt), avg(t.cnt), sum(t.cnt)
from (select count(*) as cnt, firstname, lastname
      from table
      group by firstname, lastname
     ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign an alias to the `COUNT(*)` column

```
select stddev(t.count), avg(t.count), sum(t.count)
from (select count(*) AS count, firstname, lastname
      from table
      group by firstname, lastname) t
```